# run task once all tasks on all servers completed

Tags: ansible

Consider next scenario:
  multiple hosts needs to be configured independently. At some point in time, after ALL configuration tasks on ALL hosts been completed successfully, some final tasks needs to be run on ONLY ONE host. what would be the proper solution for ansible playbook ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `run_once` for that: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once

Example:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - command: echo preparing stuff on all hosts
    - command: echo run only on single host
      run_once: True
```

Comment: thanks.. found it myself, but appreciate fast response. Unfortunately run_once doesn't work with 'free" strategy.

Comment: To fix this problem, split playbook into two plays, one with free strategy, and second without. Put run_once tasks there.